# Fast Fourier Transform using a Vandermonde Matrix - Evaluation of Co-efficients?

Tags: math, matrix, fft

Say i'm trying to evaluate the Polynomial:

```
x^2 + 1
```

Using the Fast Fourier transform method for evaluating co-efficients. Now i can change this into matrix/vector form using the co-effcient as inputs for the fast fourier transform:

so:

```
x^2 + 1 = <1, 0, 1, 0>
```

This is done by using the coefficient value e.g 1 = 1, 0x^1 = 0, X^2 = 1 and so on

Now we get to the bit where i'm totally confused. I'm meant to use the vandermonde matrix :[Vandermonde matrix ~ Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) to evaluate these values into FFT Form using the matrix:

```
1 1 1 1  
1 i-1-i
1-1 1-i
1-i 1 i
```

The output of

```
fft(1,0,1,0)
```

is

```
(2,0,2,0)
```

Now thats the step i don't quite understand, how did we use that matrix to get (2,0,2,0)?

Comment: Would "How does Fast Fourier Transform work using a Vandermonde matrix?" be a better title?

Comment: how is this programming related? it is a mtah's theory question...

Comment: @Mitch: I admit I don't know much about FFT's and could only speculate about an answer to keval's question, but I did work for several years around scientists using an FFT instrument.  It's my understanding that you can't reasonably do FFT's for real world problems without computers.  Thus I think this is programming related, moreso than a lot of what gets many upvotes on SO.

Comment: its programming related - because there is an algorithm to do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your Vandermonde matrix is incorrect.  The (4,3) entry should be -1, not 1, since the fourth row should be (-i)<sup>0</sup>, (-i)<sup>1</sup>, (-i)<sup>2</sup>, (-i)<sup>3</sup>.  Note in particular that

(-i)*(-i) = (-1)<sup>2</sup> * i<sup>2</sup> = i<sup>2</sup> = -1.

With this correction, the result follows from multiplying the Vandermonde matrix by the column vector (1,0,1,0).

Comment: ahh yes i was being careless! i can't believe i spent ages looking at it like this but now i finally get it. Now onto the next part :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could explain what your overall goal is here. I have never heard of FFTs being used to evaluate polynomials. They are used to **multiply** polynomials, or to convolve signals (an equivalent task), but I wouldn't bother unless the polynomials/signals have a large number of terms. x<sup>2</sup> + 1 isn't large. 16 terms is not large, and even 64 or 256 terms is probably better done by straightforward O(N<sup>2</sup>) techniques.

[Discrete Fourier Transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_unitary_DFT) use the matrix M<sub>ij</sub> = ω<sup>ij</sup> where ω is the Nth complex root of 1 and column/row numbering goes from 0 to N-1.

Fast Fourier Transforms never use this matrix directly, they are heavily optimized to use a divide-and-conquer technique ([Cooley-Tukey algorithm](http://www.librow.com/articles/article-10)) to calculate the end result through stages of 2x2 DFTs in series and parallel.

If you write your vector as [0,1,0,1] instead of [1,0,1,0], I think you will see that if you multiply that by the matrix you gave, you'll get [0,2,0,2]. (Although you have an error, it's

```
1 1 1 1  
1 i-1-i
1-1 1-1
1-i-1 i
```

) There must be some convention in the program you are using which reverses the order of the vector's coefficients.

Comment: thank you, i understand now. i was also wondering, if i want to turn [0,2,0,2] back to [0,1,0,1]? i know your meant to use the inverse of something.. but i'm not quite sure!

Comment: Look at the Wikipedia page on DFT: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Expressing_the_inverse_DFT_in_terms_of_the_DFT

You take the complex conjugate of the matrix and divide by N = the vector length.